# Katana OWIN versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am new to ASP.net, Katana, etc but learning fast.  One of the best practices is to use versions for the controllers.  For example:

http://localhot.com:7301/api/v1/{controller}/{connection}
   http://localhot.com:7301/api/v2/{controller}/{connection}

startup.cs :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{conn}/{cmd}",
    defaults: new 
        { 
           conn = RouteParameter.Optional, 
           cmd = RouteParameter.Optional 
        }
);
```

ConnectionController.cs  (this works)

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/Connection")]
public class ConnectionController : ApiController 
{
    public List<RadioComConnConfig> Get()
    {
        var state = ServerState.Create();
        var conList = new List<RadioComConnConfig>();
        foreach( var act in state.ActiveRadios)
        {
            conList.Add(act.CommPort);
        }
        return conList;
    }
```

This doesn't

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/Connection")]
public class V1ConnectionController : ApiController 
{
    public List<RadioComConnConfig> Get()
    {
        var state = ServerState.Create();
        var conList = new List<RadioComConnConfig>();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the old-style config routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{conn}/{cmd}",
    defaults: new 
        { 
           conn = RouteParameter.Optional, 
           cmd = RouteParameter.Optional 
        }
);
```

and use only [attribute ruoting](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enable) (as you're doing).

In your `WebApiConfig` comment this:

```
// config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
//     name: "DefaultApi",
//     routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{conn}/{cmd}",
//     defaults: new 
//         { 
//            conn = RouteParameter.Optional, 
//            cmd = RouteParameter.Optional 
//         }
// );
```

and use this:

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Your route prefix on top of your controller should be like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
```

or

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2")]
```

and define the route on your action:

```
[Route("Connection")]
public List<RadioComConnConfig> Get()
{
}
```

Comment: That worked great.  The only thing that I had a problem with as the args for the method, but quickly figured that out.  Thank you!